# Videojs - multi bitrate on VOD

Tags: video, video.js, transcoding

Hi I am using AWS elastic transcoder to transcode files to mp4, what I want to achieve is multi-bitrate for VOD. So I will create 3 different renditions and depending on what device or/and connection the user will get the best suited file.

All the files are H.264 and the bitrates are:

bitrate - 1200
bitrate - 720
bitrate - 5000

1) Am I on the right track can videojs deliver different renditions of the an MP4  out of the box or does it require dev on my side?

2) Are the presets used realistic?

3) To server up different rendition for mobile devices is it just better to use JS for device detection?

Answer (score 1):

You can use HLS to achieve this. Elastic transcoder supports creating multi-bitrate video manifests: http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2015/04/amazon-elastic-transcoder-adds_playready-drm-Support/

Then just use the HLS plugin for video.js: https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-hls